# Fetch data dynamically from json with get json method and loop the values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file from which I want to create a dynamic html elements with the JSON values. Below is the JSON file:

```
{
    "india": [
        {
            "position": "left",
            "imgurl":"3.jpg"
        },

        {
            "position": "right",
            "imgurl":"2.jpg"
        },

        {
            "position": "left",
            "imgurl":"3.jpg"
        },

        {
            "position": "right",
            "imgurl":"2.jpg"
        }
    ],

    "aus": [
        {
            "position": "left",
            "imgurl":"4.jpg"
        },

        {
            "position": "right",
            "imgurl":"2.jpg"
        },

        {
            "position": "left",
            "imgurl":"3.jpg"
        },

        {
            "position": "right",
            "imgurl":"2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the HTML file with Javascript code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>The jQuery Example</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" 
  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#driver").click(function(event) {

        $.getJSON('list1.json', function(data) {

            $.each(data.india, function (key, val) {

                $('.ms-left').append('<div class="ms-section '+val.position+'" id="left3"><img src="'+val.imgurl+'"></div>');

            });        
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>      
<body>
  <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>

  <div id = "stage" style = "background-color:#cc0;">
   STAGE</div>

<ul id="ul"></ul>
<div class="ms-left"></div>

<input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "india" />

<ul id="menu" class="">
    <li><a href="" data-value="india">India</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-value="aus">Australia</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-value="usa">USA</a></li>
</ul>       
</body>
</html>
```

I want to supply dynamic variable to each function i.e. `$.each(data.india)`.. I want to change the India to AUS, USA dynamically means data.india, data.aus etc so that `.each` will create and fetch values from JSON depending on the parameters. Please help.

How can I pass a dynamic parameter to `.each` loop that will help me fetch data based on countries defined in JSON? Currently, I can statically change the data.india, data.aus to fetch the value but I want it to be done dynamically.

I have a li structure above in code. My purpose is that when I will click the link for India, it will hit the JSON file with India value and get the data of India, same as when I will click the AUS link it will get data of AUS from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@makemelive A couple of suggestions:

- Put JS code at the end of the `<body>` tag, not inside the `<head>`.
- Use consistent indents, either tabs or spaces, prefer spaces as they are universal.

And here is the solution to your problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>The jQuery Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stage" style="background-color:#cc0;">STAGE</div>
    <div class="ms-left"></div>
    <ul id="menu" class="countries">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="india">India</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="aus">Australia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="usa">USA</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var json = {
            "india": [
                {
                    "position": "left",
                    "imgurl": "3.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "position": "right",
                    "imgurl": "2.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "position": "left",
                    "imgurl": "3.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "position": "right",
                    "imgurl": "2.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "aus": [
                {
                    "position": "left",
                    "imgurl": "4.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "position": "right",
                    "imgurl": "2.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "position": "left",
                    "imgurl": "3.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "position": "right",
                    "imgurl": "2.jpg"
                }
            ]
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        var populate = function (country) {
            $('.ms-left').empty();
            $.each(json[country], function (key, value) {
                var _div = $('<div>')
                    .addClass('ms-section')
                    .addClass(value.position)
                    .append($('<img>').attr('src', value.imgurl));

                $('.ms-left').append(_div);
            });
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            /**
             * Get your JSON here and store it in a local variable,
             * loading the file for each case is not a good practice
             * if the file is always the same.
             */

            $('.countries a').each(function() {
                $(this).on('click', populate.bind(this, $(this).data('value')));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Many many thanks for this .. can you please let me know if I want to generate position : left values first and then right values after for example :--

Comment: Want to generate like this :-

  <div class="ms-left">
   <div class="ms-section left" id="left1">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="ms-section left" id="left2">
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="ms-section left" id="left3">
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: All left values in one div and all right values in other div ...

I am pasting my HTML structure below how i want to generate :-

BELOW IS THE LEFT SECTION
<div class="ms-left">
   <div class="ms-section left" id="left1">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="ms-section left" id="left2">
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="ms-section left" id="left3">
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: BELOW IS THE RIGHT SECTION
  <div class="ms-right">
   <div class="ms-section" id="right1">
    <img src="images/img-4.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="ms-section" id="right2">
    <img src="images/img-5.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="ms-section" id="right3">
    <img src="images/img-6.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: @makemelive although I am happy to help, stackoverflow.com is not really a community where people will do your job, we are here to help you solve issues. The answer I gave you before was pretty much solving the whole issue. The next task you are trying to achieve is just a matter of logic and I am sure you will be able to sort it out just fine. :)

Comment: thank you so much for your solution .. I have managed to solved it :) its just a logic thing .

Comment: @makemelive Great, good news! - I am happy I was able to help.